# Apply CSS style within .js var

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently building a game which relies on a random number to show a particular string from an array within a .js file. What I want to do is effectively apply a span element to certain text within the array - eg. make positive outcomes green & negative red, however I can't figure out how to do this outside of html. Eg:

```
var data = [
  {"label": "Question 1", "value": 1, "question": "Awareness: High, Consistency: Low."},
  {"label": "Question 2", "value": 1, "question": "Consistency: High, Awareness: Low."},
]
```

A separate set of code, after selecting a random number, returns data[i].label. How would I set a span within js so that the "High" strings return in green, and "Low" return in red?

Cheers.

Comment: does the span element already exists? or you want to create a new one?

Comment: The question is too broad. It is not clear what have you tried and what was the problem. Please  read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Wait, the span exists and you want to pass the users input to a function. Then, If awareness is high, you want the span to be green, else lets say red? 'correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified much, but I went and did what I could.

First, your span

```
<span id="result">here we go</span>
```

The CSS file, minimalist, I did not include Bootstrap for this.

```
span {color:green}
.red{color:red}
```

The JS, the is no event, or event handler.

```
var data = [
```

{"label": "Question 1", "value": 1, "question": "Awareness: High, Consistency: Low."},
{"label": "Question 2", "value": 1, "question": "Consistency: High, Awareness: Low."}
]

The array, I have removed the trailing comma after the second object.

```
let outputs = data[0].question; This will hold the result from the array, data[0] targets the first object, you can also get map over the properties, but you have not entirely specified the scope and desired functionality.

 var output = document.getElementById('result'); // the span element
 output.innerText = outputs;                     // i prefer innerText to innerHTML
 if (outputs.includes("Consistency: Low")) {     // new string method includes, you can pass the whole ("Consistency: Low")in with no worries.
  output.classList.toggle("red");    // if condidtion is true, toggle the red class

  }
```

Codepen

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/ZwvvGV?editors=0010

Answer (score -1):

Uses classes

```js
var data = [
  {label: "Question 1", value: 1, awareness: 'High', consistency: 'Low' },
  {label: "Question 2", value: 1, awareness: 'Low', consistency: 'High' },
  {label: "Question 3", value: 1, awareness: 'Low', consistency: 'Low' },
  {label: "Question 4", value: 1, awareness: 'High', consistency: 'High' }
];

const questionElement = document.getElementById('question');
const awarenessElement = document.getElementById('awareness');
const consistencyElement = document.getElementById('consistency');

document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('click', select);

select();

function select() {
  const question = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  questionElement.innerText = question.label;
  awarenessElement.innerText = `Awareness: ${question.awareness}`;
  awarenessElement.className = question.awareness;
  consistencyElement.innerText = `Consistency: ${question.consistency}`;
  consistencyElement.className = question.consistency;
}
```

```css
.High {
  background-color: green;
}

.Low {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="question"></span>
<div id="awareness"></div>
<div id="consistency"></div>

<button id="select">Select</button>
```